# How access directly to Pentaho reports?

Tags: url, report, pentaho

I'm making some reports with Pentaho Report Designer 3.9. After publishing them, is there any way to access them directly with an URL like :

**localhost:8080/reports/my_report**

instead of:

**localhost:8080/pentaho/content/reporting/reportviewer/report.html?solution=Reports&path=%2FReports&name=my_report.prpt**

I'm using Pentaho Business Analytics 4.8 trial edition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed the reporting engine into your app and then call it via your app, documentation can be found here: http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/nav/4_3

Comment: I want to access to reports from browser, not from app; Wayne.

Answer (score 0):

considering the user is logged in already, you can find the actual request to the server upon request of the report. what I did was before hitting view report, I opened debug mode in chrome. then upon clicking the view report button, the request for the report would show up on the list

Answer (score 0):

You can Call using Following  URL

`http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/reporting/execute/steel-wheels/dashboards/newpages.pdf?solution=steel-wheels&path=/dashboards&name=my_report.prpt&userid=joe&password=password`